# Reading header tag value from a XML datatype in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

How to read the timestamp value from this XML object in T-SQL

```
 <event name="rpc_starting" package="sqlserver" timestamp="2015-05-19T22:56:21.969Z">
    <data name="connection_reset_option">
    <value>1</value>
    <text>KeepDTCXact</text>
    </data>
</event>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.value()` method like this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '
<event name="rpc_starting" package="sqlserver" timestamp="2015-05-19T22:56:21.969Z">
    <data name="connection_reset_option">
    <value>1</value>
    <text>KeepDTCXact</text>
    </data>
</event>'

SELECT @xml.value('(/event/@timestamp)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

or

```
SELECT @xml.value('(/event/@timestamp)[1]', 'datetime')
```